# How do I use Telegram API without a bot?

Tags: ruby, telegram, mtproto

I don't need a reply bot.
I want to just make a read-only call to read the channel history. Probably I need †he method https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory but documentation https://core.telegram.org/api#getting-started does not even explain the protocol.
The protocol as I understand is pretty custom and I should use some minimal wrapper but all examples/articles I've managed to find link to https://github.com/atipugin/telegram-bot-ruby but I don't need a bot.

Comment: Maybe you want to integrate the CLI https://github.com/vysheng/tg

Comment: @davidbaumann, dependencies: Lua, Python. And the last commit is 2 years old -- I don't see any mention of "supergroup" in that README. Willing to export supergroup history was my goal.

Answer (score 13):

To use `Telegram` without a bot you should work with `Telegram` low-level protocol `MTProto`. There are `MTProto` libraries for [Python](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), [JavaScript](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto) and even for [PHP](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto). See examples of getting chat history with those libraries [here](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/blob/master/docs/API_docs/methods/messages_getHistory.md), [here](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto/blob/feature/mtproto3/examples/chat-history.js) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-the-telegram-api-b0cd220dbed2)

But it seems that there is no `Ruby` `gem` for this - bad luck, you should either create `MTProto` `Ruby` `gem` yourself, either move this functional to another service written in language that has `MTProto` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tdlib-ruby](https://github.com/southbridgeio/tdlib-ruby)

```
gem 'tdlib-ruby'
```

Comment: It does not work. The README example just stucks in a loop asking for phone number. And those who managed to not have the issue earlier seem to have other issues due to the dry-rb dependency.